# domain of function with logarithmic terms.

Tags: functions, trigonometry, logarithms

what will be the domain of function given below?

$$y=1+3(\log(\sin(x))+\log(\csc(x)))$$

in book it is given this is valid for the values of angles of 1st and 2nd quadrant only.

why this function is not valid for angles of 3rd and 4th quad?

Comment: because $\sin(x)$ would be negative, of course.

Comment: cosec will also be negative then.

Comment: now i understood the reason for this. i was just using formula log(a)+log(b)=log(ab). so in this form negative sign was cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\sin x > 0\iff \csc x=\frac1{\sin x}>0$$

$$\sin x>0\iff 0<x<\pi\;\;(\text{and added multiples of }\;2\pi\;,\;\text{of course})$$

Comment: Couldn't we write: $y=1+3(\log(\sin(x))+\log(\csc(x))=1+\log(\sin^3(x))+\log(\frac{1}{\sin(x)})=1+\log(\frac{\sin^3(x)}{\sin(x)})=1+\log(\sin^2(x))$. In which case isn't the domain valid for all quadrants that $x$ lies in? Or is this simplification not allowed for some reason?

Comment: Nop @Mufasa: for you to get to $\,\log\sin^2x\;$ , you **first** had to have $\;\log\sin^3x\;,\;\;\log\sin x\;$ defined...